# Invalid messaging state in relay chain state proof

Tags: westend

i am trying to connect my parachain to a westend spec'd relay. during the syncing phase, i see the following errors in my parachain logs:

```
...
Dec 14 11:54:00 parachain[440678]: 2022-12-14 11:54:00 [Parachain]  Idle (1 peers), best: #0 (0xbbcc…7578), finalized #0 (0xbbcc…7578), ⬇ 0 ⬆ 0
Dec 14 11:54:03 parachain[440678]: 2022-12-14 11:54:03 [Relaychain]  Idle (28 peers), best: #8119539 (0x9602…e38e), finalized #8119536 (0xcda2…2389), ⬇ 15.9kiB/s ⬆ 21.6kiB/s
Dec 14 11:54:05 parachain[440678]: 2022-12-14 11:54:05 [Parachain]  Idle (1 peers), best: #0 (0xbbcc…7578), finalized #0 (0xbbcc…7578), ⬇ 0 ⬆ 0
Dec 14 11:54:06 parachain[440678]: 2022-12-14 11:54:06 [Relaychain] ✨ Imported #8119540 (0x6d07…6a15)
Dec 14 11:54:06 parachain[440678]: 2022-12-14 11:54:06 [Parachain] Starting collation. relay_parent=0x6d07642cdf23bae1d99a571a616e466b8516ecf6a688105a9831c783bd3a6a15 at=0xbbcc4f63c6f011839ec364fe5ebb1a413201f86180c9314e7646088484bf7578
Dec 14 11:54:06 parachain[440678]: 2022-12-14 11:54:06 [Parachain]  Starting consensus session on top of parent 0xbbcc4f63c6f011839ec364fe5ebb1a413201f86180c9314e7646088484bf7578
Dec 14 11:54:06 parachain[440678]: 2022-12-14 11:54:06 [Parachain] panicked at 'Invalid messaging state in relay chain state proof: DmqMqcHead(Proof)', /home/runner/.cargo/git/checkouts/cumulus-59522f43471fa161/7b1fc0e/pallets/parachain-system/src/lib.rs:407:44
Dec 14 11:54:06 parachain[440678]: 2022-12-14 11:54:06 [Parachain] 1 storage transactions are left open by the runtime. Those will be rolled back.
Dec 14 11:54:06 parachain[440678]: 2022-12-14 11:54:06 [Parachain] 1 storage transactions are left open by the runtime. Those will be rolled back.
Dec 14 11:54:06 parachain[440678]: 2022-12-14 11:54:06 [Parachain] ❗ Inherent extrinsic returned unexpected error: Error at calling runtime api: Execution failed: Execution aborted due to trap: wasm trap: wasm `unreachable` instruction executed
Dec 14 11:54:06 parachain[440678]: WASM backtrace:
Dec 14 11:54:06 parachain[440678]:     0: 0x4a5642 - <unknown>!rust_begin_unwind
Dec 14 11:54:06 parachain[440678]:     1: 0x3fdd07 - <unknown>!core::panicking::panic_fmt::h50d92a4b243b9e70
Dec 14 11:54:06 parachain[440678]:     2: 0x3fe0b9 - <unknown>!core::result::unwrap_failed::h651b815de5b19f57
Dec 14 11:54:06 parachain[440678]:     3: 0x32fd49 - <unknown>!frame_support::storage::transactional::with_storage_layer::hc06202dcec8fd746
Dec 14 11:54:06 parachain[440678]:     4: 0x381aac - <unknown>!<cumulus_pallet_parachain_system::pallet::Call<T> as frame_support::traits::dispatch::UnfilteredDispatchable>::dispatch_bypass_filter::h3b5a6fd7c0e887f9
Dec 14 11:54:06 parachain[440678]:     5: 0x20140 - <unknown>!<parachain_runtime::RuntimeCall as frame_support::traits::dispatch::UnfilteredDispatchable>::dispatch_bypass_filter::h629476e7b60ac49d
Dec 14 11:54:06 parachain[440678]:     6: 0x1dacb - <unknown>!<parachain_runtime::RuntimeCall as sp_runtime::traits::Dispatchable>::dispatch::hbbe5563907915cd6
Dec 14 11:54:06 parachain[440678]:     7: 0x15f283 - <unknown>!<fp_self_contained::checked_extrinsic::CheckedExtrinsic<AccountId,Call,Extra,SelfContainedSignedInfo> as sp_runtime::traits::Applyable>::apply::h4cef43b1174072c3
Dec 14 11:54:06 parachain[440678]:     8: 0x3fbdf - <unknown>!frame_executive::Executive<System,Block,Context,UnsignedValidator,AllPalletsWithSystem,COnRuntimeUpgrade>::apply_extrinsic::h956ceb35a0c9845f
Dec 14 11:54:06 parachain[440678]:     9: 0x289e20 - <unknown>!BlockBuilder_apply_extrinsic
Dec 14 11:54:06 parachain[440678]: . Dropping.
Dec 14 11:54:06 parachain[440678]: 2022-12-14 11:54:06 [Parachain] panicked at 'set_validation_data inherent needs to be present in every block!', /home/runner/.cargo/git/checkouts/cumulus-59522f43471fa161/7b1fc0e/pallets/parachain-system/src/lib.rs:191:13
Dec 14 11:54:06 parachain[440678]: 2022-12-14 11:54:06 [Parachain] Proposing failed: Import failed: Error at calling runtime api: Execution failed: Execution aborted due to trap: wasm trap: wasm `unreachable` instruction executed
Dec 14 11:54:06 parachain[440678]: WASM backtrace:
Dec 14 11:54:06 parachain[440678]:     0: 0x4a5642 - <unknown>!rust_begin_unwind
Dec 14 11:54:06 parachain[440678]:     1: 0x3fdd07 - <unknown>!core::panicking::panic_fmt::h50d92a4b243b9e70
Dec 14 11:54:06 parachain[440678]:     2: 0x394c03 - <unknown>!<cumulus_pallet_parachain_system::pallet::Pallet<T> as frame_support::traits::hooks::OnFinalize<<T as frame_system::pallet::Config>::BlockNumber>>::on_finalize::ha1e251bf8ac6391b
Dec 14 11:54:06 parachain[440678]:     3: 0x2cffdb - <unknown>!<(TupleElement0,TupleElement1,TupleElement2,TupleElement3,TupleElement4,TupleElement5,TupleElement6,TupleElement7,TupleElement8,TupleElement9,TupleElement10,TupleElement11,TupleElement12,TupleElement13,TupleElement14,TupleElement15,TupleElement16,TupleElement17,TupleElement18,TupleElement19,TupleElement20,TupleElement21,TupleElement22,TupleElement23,TupleElement24,TupleElement25,TupleElement26,TupleElement27,TupleElement28,TupleElement29,TupleElement30,TupleElement31,TupleElement32,TupleElement33,TupleElement34,TupleElement35,TupleElement36,TupleElement37,TupleElement38,TupleElement39,TupleElement40,TupleElement41,TupleElement42,TupleElement43,TupleElement44,TupleElement45,TupleElement46,TupleElement47) as frame_support::traits::hooks::OnFinalize<BlockNumber>>::on_finalize::h10245773698ac394
Dec 14 11:54:06 parachain[440678]:     4: 0x3fee4 - <unknown>!frame_executive::Executive<System,Block,Context,UnsignedValidator,AllPalletsWithSystem,COnRuntimeUpgrade>::idle_and_finalize_hook::hd6f0f831eaf37d83
Dec 14 11:54:06 parachain[440678]:     5: 0x3ffc9 - <unknown>!frame_executive::Executive<System,Block,Context,UnsignedValidator,AllPalletsWithSystem,COnRuntimeUpgrade>::finalize_block::h6962d7e14ec406ef
Dec 14 11:54:06 parachain[440678]:     6: 0x289ed2 - <unknown>!BlockBuilder_finalize_block
Dec 14 11:54:06 parachain[440678]:
...
```

i can connect to a locally running `westend-local` spec'd relay as well as a `rococo-local` spec'd relay just fine.
all my polkadot/substrate dependencies point to the `v0.9.30` branch.

Comment: What did you change in the spec?

Comment: these are two different specs. one is the `westend-local` that i set in the polkadot-launch config file. other is this: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/PureStake/moonbeam/runtime-1103/specs/alphanet/parachain-embedded-specs-v8.json

Comment: Could you provide more information and the steps required to reproduce your situation. I am not able to help you atm